# Unable to cancel order using magento 2 REST API

Tags: magento2

I am using following Magento 2 REST API, for cancel order-

```
hostname/magento/index.php/rest/V1/orders/1/cancel
```

where 1 is order id.
but it return always false i.e order is not cancel using this API.

then, i create a method for cancel order again no success.my method syntax is,

```
    use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;
    private $orderManagement;
    public function __construct(
           Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement)
        {

            $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
        }
        public function cancelOrder($orderId){
                $isCanceled = $this->orderManagement->cancel($orderId);
                return $isCanceled;
            }
```

and webapi.xml syntax is,

```
<route url="/V1/orders/cancelOrder/:orderId" method="GET">
        <service class="MyClient\MyProducts\Api\ProductByInterface" method="cancelOrder"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
```

what i am doing wrong please suggest me to cancel order process.

Comment: Can you show us an example request you're sending that is getting false?

Comment: hostname/magento/index.php/rest/V1/orders/cancelOrder/1

Comment: actually, my order status was completed so it can not cancel. today i created new order then new order successfully canceled.